# "Classic" menus in blueprintjs

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I'm evaluating using bluprintjs with react. Is it possible to create "classic" dropdown menus which don't use the popover component?

The popover adds an arrow to the top and expands in an odd way for drop down menus:

[image]

A more classic menu I would expect to slide open from the top and look more like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of an alternate method of constructing dropdown menus aside from using `Popover`.

However, you can create a [minimal popover](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v1/#core/components/popover.minimal-popovers) which should eliminate the arrow and behave more like a classic menu.

Comment: `Popover` in 2.0 now has a `minimal` prop that makes this process even easier!